# About $\prod{\left(1-q^n\right)^{5}}$

Tags: power-series, infinite-product, q-series

Is there a result about the non-vanishing of coefficients of 
$$\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\left(1-q^n\right)^{5}}=1-5q+5q^2+10q^3-15q^4-6q^5-5q^6+25q^7+15q^8-20q^9+\cdots \text{ ?}$$

Thanks !

Comment: By non-vanishing of coefficients you mean every coefficient is nonzero?

Comment: Just a note: $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^n) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} (-1)^n q^{(3n^2-n)/2}$.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean mezhang.

Comment: @Dane, plotting truncated versions of each side yields very different graphs.  Could you expand on your statement?

Comment: @AntonioVargas What I wrote above is called Euler's [pentagonal number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem). Since the original question is about the coefficients of the fifth power of this series, I thought it might be relevant somehow.

Comment: @Dane, my mistake, I didn't notice the exponent was missing from your equation.  Sorry about that!